# Como reiniciar un servicio

Tags: cmd, server

Tengo un servicio de un sistema que permite comunicacion entre terminales y servidor, pero al parecer tengo que reiniciar manualmente ese servicio para que establezca comunicación, ya que al encender el servidor, sí aparece iniciado pero no permite comunicación.

Me gustaria saber como programar el reinicio de ese servicio cuando se inicie el servidor.

Comment: En qué sistema operativo? Cómo está definido el servicio? Por qué no revisar primero qué dicen los logs del servicio para ver si no se necesita reiniciarlo? Has revisado `sc.exe` ?

Comment: El servicio es de unos sistemas contables, se instalan en servidor y terminales. Ese servicio está en un servidor con Server 2019. Lo raro es que tenemos otros servidores y no pasa eso.

Comment: Más allá de lo que te dicen en la respuesta y te indico en el comentario, no hay mucho más que hacer porque no sabemos por qué falla el servicio y no tenemos cómo probar hipótesis. Revisa el Visor de Eventos de Windows y busca eventos de error asociados a tu servicio.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia Ivan, para poder realizar lo que quieres hacer es de la siguiente manera:

-Lo primero que haremos será abrir el menú de Ejecutar de Windows. Para ello pulsamos la combinación de teclas Windows  + R.
-En el menú de Ejecutar escribimos services.msc y pulsamos el botón de Aceptar.

-Con esto ya estaremos en la ventana de administración de Servicios en dónde podremos Iniciar, Detener y Desactivar los servicios que necesitemos.

-Al hacer doble clic encima de algún proceso, podemos ver el estado en el que se encuentra y el tipo de inicio que tiene, ahi deberas escoger el que mejor se adecue a tus necesidades, te recomiendo poner la opcion de automatico, para evitar iniciarlo manualmente y para que se inicie cada vez que enciendas el ordenador. Saludos...

Comment: Gracias por responder. Lo que pasa es que así está actualmente. El servicio está para iniciar en automatica, de hecho si inicia al encender el servidor, pero como que no está trabajando correctamente o se bloquea, tengo que reiniciar ese servicio y solo asi ya hay comunicacion entre terminales y servidor. Por ello busco como reiniciar ese servicio cuando se encienda el servidor.

Comment: Podría probar a configurar el inicio a "Automático (diferido)" para que espere a que los servicios del OS estén disponibles.